# Please help me to write a test class wrapper class passing parameter of this in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

```
Public Class WrapperClassEx
   {
     public list<TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c > listofcontactrole{get;set;}
     Public string propertyname{get;set;}
     Public string propertyid{get;set;}

     Public WrapperClassEx(string JCity,string propertyid){        
        this.propertyid = propertyid;
        propertyname=JCity;    
        listofcontactrole =  new   list<TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c >();          
     }
   }
```

---

testclass

```
public with sharing class ShowPropertyRelated_UnitTest 
{
    static testMethod void CheckTest()
    {      
       TTL_Residential__Property__c testContact = new TTL_Residential__Property__c();

      // List<TTL_Residential__Property__c>  oppList =[SELECT Id,name FROM TTL_Residential__Property__c LIMIT 20];
       List<TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c> oppList=[select id,TTL_Core__Contact__c,TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c,TTL_Commercial__Property__c from TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c where TTL_Commercial__Property__c ='a0H63000000lFCGEA2' ]; 
      // ApexPages.StandardSetController setCtr = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(oppList);
       ApexPages.StandardSetController setCtr = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(oppList);
       setCtr.setSelected(oppList);
       TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c obj2  = new TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c(TTL_Commercial__Property__c ='a0H63000000lFCGEA2',TTL_Commercial__Property__r.Name='test',TTL_Core__Contact__c='00363000001h2ZfAAI', TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c='Owner');
       insert obj2;
       String str1='a0H63000000lFCGEA2';
       String str2='test';
    //  setCtr.setSelected(new TTL_Residential__Property__c[]{testContact});     
   PropertyRelatedController  controller = new PropertyRelatedController();
                          controller.WrapperClassEx obj = new controller.WrapperClassEx(str1, str2,obj2);
                          controller.getContactNames();
                          controller.getItems();
                          controller.UpdateRecord();
                          controller.abc();

    }
}
```

---

Controller

```
public  class PropertyRelatedController 
{
// declaration Start
   public  List<String> str1;
   String newSetStr ;
   String Selectedstr;
   public  string ContactIds{get;set;}

   // public  string ContactIds1{get;set;}
   list<Contact> con =new list<Contact>();
   list<CampaignMember> cmem = new list<CampaignMember>();
   public TTL_Residential__Property__c cp{get;set;}
   Public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList{get;set;}
   public  list<string> ContactId = new list<string>();
   public  list<string> ContactId1 = new list<string>();
   public  list<string> ContactId2 = new list<string>();
   Set<Id> accountId = new Set<ID>();

   public string selectedValue{get;set;}

 // Controller start from here           
   public PropertyRelatedController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController) 
   {
            for(Sobject standcont:standardController.getSelected())
          {
               accountId.add(standcont.id);
          } 
           cp = new TTL_Residential__Property__c();
           selectedValue='';
            system.debug('chechk'+Selectedstr);
          // ContactIds = new list<string>();
           ContactId.clear();  
            getwrapperObj();
   }
     public void getContactNames()
    { 
     Selectedstr = selectedValue;

      getwrapperObj();
    }
      public List<SelectOption> getItems()
     {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('All','--All--'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Primary Owner or Owner','Primary Owner and Owner '));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Primary Owner','Primary Owner'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Owner','Owner'));

        return options;
     }


// Wrapper Class Starts from Here 

   Public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj()
   {
   WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();
   map<string,TTL_Residential__Property__c> mapofproperty = new map<string,TTL_Residential__Property__c>();
    For( TTL_Residential__Property__c propobject :[ select id,name from TTL_Residential__Property__c where id in:accountId ])
     {
             mapofproperty.put(propobject.id,propobject);
      }
      set<string> setofid = new set<string>();
      map<string,WrapperClassEx> mapofwrapper = new map<string,WrapperClassEx>();

     if(Selectedstr != null && Selectedstr!='Primary Owner or Owner' && Selectedstr!='All' )
     {
       ContactId.clear();

       system.debug('cid'+ContactId);
     for(TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c contactrole : [select id,TTL_Core__Contact__c,TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c,TTL_Commercial__Property__c,TTL_Core__Contact__r.Account.Name from TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c where TTL_Commercial__Property__c in:mapofproperty.keyset() and TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c =: Selectedstr])
    {
           ContactId.add(contactrole.TTL_Core__Contact__c);
            system.debug('cid2'+ContactId);

        if(!setofid.contains(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c))
        {
            setofid.add(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c);
            mapofwrapper.put(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id,New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
            WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
        }
        else
        {
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
        }
    }   
    }
        else if(Selectedstr=='Primary Owner or Owner' && Selectedstr!='All')
       {
            ContactId.clear();
         for(TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c contactrole : [select id,TTL_Core__Contact__c,TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c,TTL_Commercial__Property__c,TTL_Core__Contact__r.Account.Name from TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c where TTL_Commercial__Property__c in:mapofproperty.keyset() and (TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c = 'Owner' or TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c = 'Primary Owner')])
        {
          //  system.debug('Contactid'+ContactId);
           ContactId.add(contactrole.TTL_Core__Contact__c);
        if(!setofid.contains(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c))
        {
            setofid.add(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c);
            mapofwrapper.put(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id,New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
           // WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
        }
        else
        {
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
        }
    }   
    }
     else if( Selectedstr=='All')
    {
       ContactId.clear();
         for(TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c contactrole : [select id,TTL_Core__Contact__c,TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c,TTL_Commercial__Property__c,TTL_Core__Contact__r.Account.Name from TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c where TTL_Commercial__Property__c in:mapofproperty.keyset()])
    {
          //  system.debug('Contactid'+ContactId);
           ContactId.add(contactrole.TTL_Core__Contact__c);
        if(!setofid.contains(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c))
        {
            setofid.add(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c);
            mapofwrapper.put(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id,New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
           // WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
        }
        else
        {
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
        }
    }   
    }
     else 
    {
         for(TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c contactrole : [select id,TTL_Core__Contact__c,TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c,TTL_Commercial__Property__c,TTL_Core__Contact__r.Account.Name from TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c where TTL_Commercial__Property__c in:mapofproperty.keyset()])
        {
          //  system.debug('Contactid'+ContactId);
           ContactId.add(contactrole.TTL_Core__Contact__c);
           if(!setofid.contains(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c))
          {
            setofid.add(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c);
            mapofwrapper.put(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id,New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
           // WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).name,mapofproperty.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c ).id ));
          }
          else
         {
            mapofwrapper.get(contactrole.TTL_Commercial__Property__c).listofcontactrole.add(contactrole);
         }
       }   
    }
     WrapperList.addall(mapofwrapper.values());
  //   abc();
      return WrapperList;
   }  
   Public Class WrapperClassEx
   {
     public list<TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c > listofcontactrole{get;set;}
     Public string propertyname{get;set;}
     Public string propertyid{get;set;}

     Public WrapperClassEx(string JCity,string propertyid){        
        this.propertyid = propertyid;
        propertyname=JCity;    
        listofcontactrole =  new   list<TTL_Core__Contact_Role__c >();          
     }
   } 
   // Add to Campaign....

    public void UpdateRecord()
    {
       list<CampaignMember> updtlst= new list<CampaignMember>();

       for(Contact  obj2 :[select Id , Name from Contact where id in:ContactId])
        {
                          con.add(obj2);
        }  
      //  ContactId.clear();  
        Set<String> setOfContactId = new Set<String>();
        for(CampaignMember obj: [select Id ,ContactId,CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId =:cp.Campaign_Lookup__c ])
        {
              setOfContactId.add(obj.ContactId);
        }

        for(Contact conlst:con)
        {  

               if(!setOfContactId.Contains(conlst.Id))
               {
                CampaignMember camp= new CampaignMember();
                camp.CampaignId = cp.Campaign_Lookup__c;

                camp.ContactId = conlst.Id;

                updtlst.add(camp);
             //   system.debug(updtlst);
                }
        }
       if(updtlst.size()>0)
           insert updtlst;  

           ContactId.clear();
           con.clear();
          cp.Campaign_Lookup__c=null;

    }

 /*  public  void abc()
   {          
         newSetStr = '';
         For(String str:ContactId)
         {
            newSetStr +=  str + ',';
         }

         if(newSetStr !='')
         {
         newSetStr = newSetStr.substring(0,newSetStr.length()-1);

         ContactIds=newSetStr ;
         }
   }*/
 }
```

Comment: The controller will have a instance variable of the wrapper class. You need to initialize that variable in your test class. Please post your whole controller to understand better.

Comment: please some help asap

Comment: controller. getwrapperObj() in your test class will cover the wrapper class.

Comment: but it is not as  code coverage is 48% only

Comment: can u please send me the test class for this litle bit similer

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE arjun. You'll find that people will be more willing to spend time helping you with these kinds of problems if you tell them which lines of code aren't covered by your test class (hint: knowing the line number isn't helpful since we can't tell the number when viewing it here, so mark you code sections).

Comment: I see a hard-coded ID in the test method -- not best practice and will likely lead to deployment failure. All test data should be mocked